# Remove all files that match name in a list

Tags: script, file, automation, macos

I have a folder with a lot of images.

My client sent me a list of rejected images I need to delete from that folder.

The list is like this: `_001,_002,_003,_004,_006,_007,RAM08953,RAM08995,RAM08996,RAM09039,RAM09060,RAM09087,RAM09101,RAM09104,RAM09115,RAM09126,RAM09170,RAM09171,RAM09172,RAM09176,RAM09188`.

How can I easily run something that delete those files, or move those files inside a new folder or something without doing by hand? It can be an app, shell script or any tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete a list of comma separated filenames using a CSV by using the following command:

```
for file in $( cat foo.csv | awk '{gsub(",","\n"); print $0}' ); do rm $file; done
```

You can make it safer by moving the file to the Trash instead of deleting it:

```
for file in $( cat foo.csv | awk '{gsub(",","\n"); print $0}' ); do mv $file ~/.Trash; done
```

**How this works**

This is a FOR/DO loop that first takes the contents of `foo.csv` and

- `cat foo.csv |`  This outputs the entire contents of the CSV file and pipes it to the next command
- `awk '{gsub(",","\n"); print $0}`  This line takes the output of the previous command and using the `awk` text processing utility then substitutes the comma (`,`) for the newline character (`\n`).  It then outputs each item (`print $0`) on a separate line
- each line becomes an "item" for the FOR loop to iterate.
- for every item it will issue the command  `rm $file`
- You can delete/move/rename/whatever each file by modifying the command after `do`.  (Eg. `do mv $file ~/Foo/Bar/$file` to move it to another folder.)

Comment: Needless use of `cat` and `|` as `awk` will read the _file_ as an _argument_, that is to say,`"$(awk '{gsub(/,/, "\n")}1' foo.csv)"`, is all that's required.

Comment: @user3439894 - Ok...your's is shorter and more efficient, but I like my method since I don't use `awk` but once in a blue moon and it flows with my coding style.  There's nothing "needless" about any of it.

Comment: You said "_There's nothing "needless" about any of it._", well the use of an unnecessary external command and pipe, when it is not at all needed, is indeed needless! I certainly do not mean anything derogatory by what I've said and while you may not use `awk` that often and while my `awk` _command_ is more compact, nonetheless, that was not the main point being made. I'm only pointing out what's generally considered to be a very poor programing paradigm. FWIW I too use to code in that same poor manner but learned to do it better as a result of comments like these.

Comment: Point taken.   Allow me to share one with you... Beginning your "critique" with the word "needless" is pejorative.

Answer (score 1):

To delete a list of comma separated filenames from a folder, you can use the following:

```
tr , '\n' <<< "file.jpg,second.jpg,…" | xargs -I{} rm /path/to/folder/{}
```

Replace `file.jpg,second.jpg,…` with your comma separated list of files.
Replace `/path/to/folder` with the path to the containing folder of the images.

`tr , '\n'` replaces commas in the input with new lines. `xargs` takes the lines and runs the given command for each line, replacing `{}` with each line input (as instructed by `-I{}`). `tr` is used since `xargs` in macOS does not support `-d` for a custom delimiter.

However, I notice that your list does not include file extensions. You can add the extension to the end of the command instead.

```
tr , '\n' <<< "file,second,…" | xargs -I{} rm /path/to/folder/{}.jpg
```